# Android Studio fails to open on Mac OS Snow Leopard - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Toolkit

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, osx-snow-leopard

I'm facing this weird issue where Android Studio just doesn't open anymore. I've been using Android Studio for quite a while now and everything was working great but all of a sudden, it stopped opening for some reason. I am using the following configuration:

Android Studio 0.5.9
Java version "1.6.0_51"
Mac OS 10.6.8

If it helps, here's the stack trace I was able to fetch from "console":

> [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]: Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Toolkit 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:237) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:226) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext.initMainAppContext(AppContext.java:226) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext.access$200(AppContext.java:112) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:299) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext.getAppContext(AppContext.java:280) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext$6.getContext(AppContext.java:827) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaAWTAccess(SharedSecrets.java:144) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.util.logging.LogManager.getUserContext(LogManager.java:321) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:894) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:369) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:290) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:321) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.awt.Component.(Component.java:173) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:216) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:203) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:86) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]: Exception in thread
>   "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Toolkit 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:237) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:226) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext.initMainAppContext(AppContext.java:226) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext.access$200(AppContext.java:112) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:299) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext.getAppContext(AppContext.java:280) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.awt.AppContext$6.getContext(AppContext.java:827) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaAWTAccess(SharedSecrets.java:144) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.util.logging.LogManager.getUserContext(LogManager.java:321) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.util.logging.LogManager.contexts(LogManager.java:352) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.util.logging.LogManager.reset(LogManager.java:999) 
>   [0x0-0x67067].com.google.android.studio[2226]:    at
>   java.util.logging.LogManager$Cleaner.run(LogManager.java:219)

I have tried restarting the machine, reinstalling android studio, reinstalling java, setting java home path, but nothing has helped. Please let me know if anyone of you might know the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat. That is because it's looking for jdk1.7 and I found out that 1.7 doesn't work in Snow Leopard 10.6. I tried installing it and it said I need to have Mac OSx 10.7.